# django Error : Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named comments

Tags: python, django, importerror, django-1.3

I am currently porting over some django 0.97 code to django 1.3.1 code.

I keep getting the following django error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /dir1/dir2/
Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named comments
```

The error keeps pointing to the following line
    `<a href = "{% url testpage %}">testpage</a>`

I do have 'django.contrib.comments' in my settings.py file. I am running django 1.3.1 and python 2.7.

The trace shows the following error

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module
__import__(name)
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
name    'django.contrib.comments.urls.comments'
package None
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Update 1:
I am Looking into this 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/comments/upgrade/

Update 2: To solve my problem I did the following.

Changed

```
(r'^admin/', include('django.contrib.admin.urls')),
```

to

```
(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

changed

```
(r'^comments/', include('django.contrib.comments.urls.comments')),
```

to

```
(r'^comments/', include('django.contrib.comments.urls')),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your url patterns where you include the comments urls. The [comments quick start guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/) says you should have something like:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    (r'^comments/', include('django.contrib.comments.urls')),
    ...
)
```

Whereas you error message in the traceback suggests you may have `django.contrib.comments.urls.comments` hardcoded somewhere.

Comment: Thanks.I made changes to the urls.py file to fix this problem. See my update in the question.